# catch block isn't getting my errors from the fetch api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, error-handling

I have a code that is exactly the same as the image. The fetch method is wrapped ina catch block, both it just doesn't, catch the error. From my node backend, I've tried different methods of rendering the error so it can be caught on the frontend.

[image: React Code to handle error]

```js
const  errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    if (typeof (err) === "string") {
        // custom application error
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
    }

    if (err.name === "UnauthorizedError") {
        // jwt authentication error
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid Token" });
    }
    if (err.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
        // jwt authentication error
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid Token" });
    }

    // default to 500 server error
    return res.status(501).render("error" , { message: err.message });

};
```

This is my node backend

Comment: It will only get to the catch when you are disconnected. You should check [response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Differences_from_jQuery) and maybe throw if not ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check errors with this simple function

```
handleFetchErrors (response) {
    if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText)
    return response
}
```